# error launching in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

i work [Configure Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config.html) on Customize your VM options

after this when i run android studio, i get error:
[image]

and this environment variables:
[image]

what's problem?

Comment: whats your machine bit type? x64 or x86?

Comment: x64 windows 10.

Comment: do you have another folder called program files(x64) or something?

Comment: @AjayP.Prajapati no

Comment: i re-install android studio but not working

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GwU4AJn0Txg - Go through this video.. and do yourself, would be good learning for you..

Comment: i see this video,but not working!

Comment: Also copy the same path for environmental variable too , you are adding in just system environment. Also hoping you downloaded 64bit JDK.. that should solve your problem

Comment: my JDK is 64bit

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your JDK is 64-bit and system-compatible. What files did you specifically change in your VM options?

Comment: i set -XmxheapSize:-Xmx2g but i think it's worng